# How to add a constant using Lag/Max Window Function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

Please refer to sample table below.  My table has ID, ID_Type, Lag, and Row_Num.  I need to create the "New_Col" column below.  I come close using the MAX window function, but I still have not had success.  Any help would be much appreciated—if a window function is not the way to go I am definitely open to suggestions.

Here is the SQL I used to arrive at the Sample Table below:

```
SELECT ID,
       ID_TYPE,
       LAG(ID_TYPE) OVER (ORDER BY Row_Num) AS Lag,
       Row_Num
FROM (SELECT ID,
             CASE WHEN ID LIKE '%Exc%' 
                  THEN ID
             END AS ID_Type,
             Row_Num
      FROM Source_Table)
```

Sample Table:

```
ID       ID_Type  Lag       Row_Num
Exc      Exc                1
10R46             Exc       2
10R46                       3
100R91                      4
Non_Exc  Non_Exc            5 
10R91             Non_Exc   6
10M95                       7
```

Desired Output:

```
ID       ID_Type  Lag       New_Col  Row_Num
Exc                         Exc      1
10R46    Exc                Exc      2
10R46             Exc       Exc      3
100R91                      Exc      4
Non_Exc  Non_Exc            Non_Exc  5 
10R91             Non_Exc   Non_Exc  6
10M95                       Non_Exc  7
```

Comment: Please provide the SQL to create your source table and some sample data.  It looks like you are halfway down a bad path to take and are asking us to carry on from there.  I get the impression an entirely different solution to the one you have started here will be best.

Comment: @iamdave, The source table is actually a scheduled (Excel) report out of a property management system. I did not create the table, rather I loaded the Excel file into Domo (BI tool), which then converts the file into a table. Within Domo I can use either Redshift or MySQL for additional ETL work.

Comment: What is your expected output? Considering sample data is input..

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, the "New_Col" in the "Desired Output" is what I hope to achieve.

Comment: @izzy84, can you explain the logic in plain English behind New_Col? I am curious because row num 5 seems to have Non_Exc as the new col value whereas your max(lag) will not have encountered the lag value of Non_Exc by row 5.

Comment: @DotThoughts, I edited my original post to show the SQL I used to create the Sample Table.  The "New_Col" is actually the ID_Type, but the source table listed the ID_Type as a value in the ID column, because it is an Excel Flat File that was loaded into a BI tool I use called Domo.  If I can create the New_Col I will then DELETE the rows that contain 'Exc' and 'Non_Exc' in the ID column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an IGNORE NULLS specification to the LAG window function achieves what I was looking for.

```
SELECT ID,
       ID_TYPE,
       LAG(ID_TYPE IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY Row_Num) AS Lag,
       Row_Num
FROM (SELECT ID,
             CASE WHEN ID LIKE '%Exc%' 
                  THEN ID
             END AS ID_Type,
             Row_Num
      FROM Source_Table)
```

Returns:

```
ID       ID_Type  Lag       Row_Num
Exc      Exc                1
10R46             Exc       2
10R46             Exc       3
100R91            Exc       4
Non_Exc  Non_Exc  Exc       5 
10R91             Non_Exc   6
10M95             Non_Exc   7
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to generate range keys

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID varchar(50),ID_Type varchar(50),Lag varchar(50),Row_Num int)
Insert into @YourTable values
('Exc','Exc','',1),
('10R46','','Exc',2),
('10R46','','',3),
('100R91','','',4),
('Non_Exc','Non_Exc','',5),
('10R91','','Non_Exc',6),
('10M95','','',7)

;with cteR1 as (Select ID_Type,R1=min(Row_Num) from @YourTable Where ID_Type<>'' Group by ID_Type
   ), cteR2 as (Select A.ID_Type,A.R1,R2=isnull(min(B.R1),9999)-1 From cteR1 A Left Join cteR1 B on (B.R1>A.R1) Group By A.ID_Type,A.R1)
Select A.ID
      ,A.ID_Type
      ,A.Lag 
      ,New_Col=B.ID_Type
      ,A.Row_Num
 From @YourTable A
 Join cteR2 B on Row_Num between R1 and R2
 Order By Row_Num
```

Returns

```
ID      ID_Type Lag     Row_Num New_Col
Exc     Exc             1       Exc
10R46           Exc     2       Exc
10R46                   3       Exc
100R91                  4       Exc
Non_Exc Non_Exc         5       Non_Exc
10R91           Non_Exc 6       Non_Exc
10M95                   7       Non_Exc
```